# Turning PHP key=>value into sub array: [key,value]

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having following data:

```
Array ( [one] => this [two] => this2 )
```

Which I want to convert to json type which looks like:

```
data:{[one,this],[two,this2]}
```

How can I get through this in effecient manner?

Edit: 
I've tried a lot of things This is actual data which I need to make datatable compatible:

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":null,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":‌​[[{"first":[""],"sec‌​ond":[""],"third":["‌​"],"fourth":[""],"fi‌​fth":[""],"sixth":["‌​value"]}]]}
```

as the data here is in key=>value form json is not compatible for datatables (PHP)

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried a lot of things
This is actual data which I need to make datatable compatible:
`
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":null,"recordsFiltered":null,"data":[[{"first":[""],"second":[""],"third":[""],"fourth":[""],"fifth":[""],"sixth":["value"]}]]}
`

as the data here is in key=>value form json is not compatible for datatables (PHP)

Comment: Chirag, if my answer does not help you reach the solution, then please add what should be converted to what and how is it not doing so.

Comment: Please check my comment on your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) and [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php):

```
$result = array_map(null, array_keys($array), $array);

$json = json_encode($result);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1ba69ac5901d8e1d692146c304761b0768fa738).